# Whats the text meant to say by comparison with |x-2| slower faster thing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to check the differentiability at $x= 2$ of the function $f(x) = |\cos(\pi/x)|$. A quote from my textbook shows an idea which can be applied to check it:

> Thus the problem is reduced to checking the differentiability of the function, say $|k(x)|$ (where $k(r) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$) at $x = 2$. Here the crucial point is that the absolute value function is differentiable everywhere except where it takes the value $0$. In the present case, in a small neighbourhood of $x = 2$, the function $k(s)$ vanishes only at $x = 2$. However, from this we must not hastily conclude that $|k(x)|$ is not differentiable at $x = 2$. What matters is not just that $|k(x)| \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 2$ but how rapidly. If it tends to $0$ more rapidly than $|x — 2|$ then $|k(x)|$ would indeed be differentiable at $x = 2$ with a vanishing derivative. (For example, the functions $|(x — 2)^3|$ or $|\sin^{3/2}(x — 2)|$ are differentiable at $x = 2$.) On the other hand, if $|k(x)|$ tends to $0$ at a rate slower than or comparable to that of $|x — 2|$, then $|k(x)|$ is not differentiable at $x = 2$. (In the former case, the right and left handed derivatives don't exist while in the latter they exist but are unequal. The two cases are illustrated, for example, by $\sqrt{|x-2|}$ and $|\sin(x — 2)|$ respectively.)
>
> [Image of quote if you need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hESkh.jpg)

In reference to the context said above in the quote, for the case where we check $|k(x)|$ at $x=2$, why is it true that if the modulus of the rate of change at that point (where the doubt of differentiability is) is greater than $1$, then it's differentiable there, otherwise it's not (I assumed this to be the meaning from the text)? Can anyone show why /prove this fact?

Comment: What is the text you are using? When asking a question like this it is *always* helpful to tell us what you are reading.

Comment: I have no idea what "why is it true that if the rate of change at that point where a doubt of differentiability is there is greater (modulus) than 1 , then its differentiable there otherwise not ?" means. (I also don't see what it has to do with that quote...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich then what does the quote mean by rate comparison to |x-2| slower ,faster ?

Comment: I edited the title , i think i didnt get the text meaning

Comment: I can't figure out how to state it more clearly than in the book. If $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to2$ faster than $|x-2|$ then $f$ is differentiable at $2$ and $f'(2)=0$.

Comment: The text says "If it tends to $0$ more rapidly than $|x-2|\ldots$" How did you get from there to "if the rate of change at that point where a doubt of differentiability is there is greater (modulus) than 1 , then its differentiable"? You have it backwards, don't you?

Comment: Hmm so isnt that means as the rate of change in case of |x-2| is from -1 to 1 instantly , what is the rate of change in case of f(x) faster means ?? That i didnt get at all

Comment: Ik @TonyK  i didnt quite get the meaning can a example be given by comparison ? As answer

Comment: " rate of change in case of |x-2| is from -1 to 1 instantly" ??? "rate of change" means _derivative_.

Comment: Sir that was just a bit misunderstanding now i got it , can u pls check.the comment below im your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure what the question is. It seems possible that the question is what does it mean to say one function tends to zero faster than another.

> > **Def.** Suppose $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=\lim_{x\to2}g(x)=0$. We say $f\to0$ "faster than" $g$ as $x\to2$ if $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)/g(x)=0$.

So if $f(x)\to0$ faster than $x-2$ as $x\to2$ then the definition of the derivative says exactly that $f'(2)=0$.

Comment: Sir now i see what that means ,thanks , so if we r given to find diffenretiability of |cos(pi/x)| at x=2 using only basic Left hand deriviative and right hand derivative calculation how one arrives at non differemtiability as such what i got was RHD is lim h tends to zero of |cos(pi/2+h)|/h and LHD lim h tends to zero -|cos(pi/2-h)|/h , how to progress now that mod thing is kinda troubling here in basic approach

Comment: If $h>0$ is small then $\cos(\pi/(2+h))>0$ and $\cos(\pi/(2-h))<0$. Use the first to find the rhd and the second for the lhd.